# Is it possible to achieve 'or' in Active Record with an 'includes'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am trying to query from within an ActiveRecord model, let's call it `user`:

- user `has_many :projects`
- projects `has_one :thing`
- user `has_many :things, through: :projects`

I am interested in finding all `projects` that either have `things` that are `completed` or don't have `things` at all.

A few attempts:

```
projects.includes(:thing).where(
  things: { status: :complete }
).or(
  things: { id: nil }
)
```

or

```
projects.includes(:thing).where(
  things: [
    { status: :complete }, 
    { id: nil }
  ]
)
```

I'd prefer to accomplish this without SQL if possible even if it's something like this:

```
query = projects.includes(:thing)
query.where(things: {id: nil}) & query.where(things: {status: :complete})
```

Comment: Actually, I would like to add an `.order(:start_date)` to the results, so I cannot use `&` as that will return an array, not an activerecord relation.  Can anyone make this one query?

Comment: I am interested to see if there is a way to do this maybe with a partial sql query. But still let activerecord to handle the 'includes'.

Comment: If your only problem is ordering, you can do the ordering first and the mapping next. Like projects.order(:start_date).map etcetera

Answer (score 0):

So this may or may not work for you, but try

query = projects.includes(:thing)
query.where(things: {id: nil}).joins( query.where(things: {status: :complete}) )

I can't test this myself atm, but I'm really curious if it would actually join the two queries together. I'll play around with it later